Obtaining SAR for my patch antenna in HFSS
I have designed an implantable patch antenna for biomedical applications and I have obtained SAR values which looks like this in the image below. This is Average SAR and I couldn't get local SAR for reason I am unaware of. My goal is to obtain SAR similar to the figure 18 in the below image.
